# Port OpenGl buffer to XNA

Tags: c#, opengl, xna, opentk, monogame

I am trying to port an application with some OpenTK (C# Opengl implementation) to XNA/MonoGame and I have come to a buffer, but I cannot figure out how to port this because there does not seem to be any direct equivilant of the buffer functions. I am trying to port this code:

```
public void RefillVBO()
        {
            if (positions == null) return;
            if (hasBuf)
                GL.DeleteBuffers(3, buf);
            GL.GenBuffers(3, buf);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, buf[0]);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(positions.Length * sizeof(float)), positions, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            if (normals != null)
            {
                GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, buf[1]);
                GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(normals.Length * sizeof(float)), normals, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            }
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, buf[2]);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(elementsLength * sizeof(int)), elements, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            hasBuf = true;
        }
```

Could anyone please translate this for me and possibly explain what is going on because I have no idea?

Also, is there any porting guide or something for this because there are literally hundreds of other errors related to "Gl" functions.

Answer (score 1):

In XNA you usually create a struct type that contains the vertex' data (e.g. position, normal...). Based on that type you create a `VertexDeclaration` that tells the GPU how to interpret the data. Finally you create a `VertexBuffer` and set the data. Optionally you can create an index buffer.

Take a look at these links:

[How To: Create and Use a Custom Vertex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976065%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)

[Improving performance by using VertexBuffers and IndexBuffers](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/VertexBuffer_and_IndexBuffer.php)